# Return result by join to array in object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, frameworks, laravel-5

I have 2 table:
**orders**(order_id,order_code,user_id,full_name,phone,address,recieve_address,total_product,total_price,status,created_at,updated_at)

**detail_order**(id,order_id,order_code,product_id,price,quantity,total_amount,created_at,updated_at)

Query to get data:

```
$id=Auth::user()->id;

$result=DB::table('orders')->join('detail_orders', function ($join) use($id) {
    $join->on('orders.order_id', '=', 'detail_orders.order_id')
    ->where('orders.user_id', '=', $id);
})->get();
```

My result when dd($result) :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#194 ▼
    +"order_id": 37
    +"order_code": "Order00003"
    +"user_id": 1
    +"full_name": "Duc.VUong"
    +"phone": "01203388870"
    +"address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"recieve_address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"total_product": 2
    +"total_price": 1450000.0
    +"status": 0
    +"created_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"updated_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"id": 29
    +"product_id": 1
    +"price": 800000.0
    +"quantity": 1
    +"total_amount": 800000.0
  }
  1 => {#187 ▼
    +"order_id": 37
    +"order_code": "Order00003"
    +"user_id": 1
    +"full_name": "Duc.VUong"
    +"phone": "01203388870"
    +"address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"recieve_address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"total_product": 2
    +"total_price": 1450000.0
    +"status": 0
    +"created_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"updated_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"id": 30
    +"product_id": 2
    +"price": 650000.0
    +"quantity": 1
    +"total_amount": 650000.0
  }
]
```

If i want to result look like this:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#194 ▼
    +"order_id": 37
    +"order_code": "Order00003"
    +"user_id": 1
    +"full_name": "Duc.VUong"
    +"phone": "01203388870"
    +"address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"recieve_address": "445/33b bình đông"
    +"total_product": 2
    +"total_price": 1450000.0
    +"status": 0
    +"created_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"updated_at": "2017-04-12 17:01:38"
    +"detail":[
    0=>{
        +"product_id": 1
        +"price": 800000.0
        +"quantity": 1
        +"total_amount": 800000.0
    }
    1=>{
        +"product_id": 2
        +"price": 650000.0
        +"quantity": 1
        +"total_amount": 650000.0
    }
    ] 
  }
]
```

The detail in object of array will get by order_id. So how can i do it by query?

Comment: Do you need to use `DB` or could you use Eloquent for this? It would be easier to achieve what you need

Comment: Yes , i want to use db. How can i do it by query builder?

Comment: I don't think there is a method to do that using DB.

Comment: what you exactly want\.It is pain to read your question